# Python appending to List from a nested Dictionary

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dictionary like the example below:

```py
dev_dict = {
    "switch-1": {"hostname": "switch-1.nunya.com", "location": "IDF01"},
    "switch-2": {"hostname": "switch-2.nunya.com", "location": "IDF02"},
    "...": {"hostname": "...", "location": "..."},
    "switch-30": {"hostname": "switch-30.nunya.com", "location": "IDF30"},
    "router-1": {"hostname": "router-a-1.nunya.com", "location": "MDF"},
    "core-1": {"hostname": "core-1.nunya.com", "location": "MDF"},
    "...": {"hostname": "...", "location": "..."},
}
```

I'm appending the dictionaries to a list using this code:

```py
dev_list = []
for i in dev_dict:
    dev_list.append(dev_dict[i])
```

Which generates a list like this:

```py
dev_list = [
    {"hostname": "switch-30.nunya.com", "location": "IDF30"},
    {"hostname": "core-1.nunya.com", "location": "MDF"},
    {"hostname": "switch-2.nunya.com", "location": "IDF02"},
    {"hostname": "...", "location": "..."},
    {"hostname": "router-1.nunya.com", "location": "MDF"}
    {"hostname": "...", "location": "..."},
]
```

What I would like to accomplish is to have the list that's generated be in a certain order based on the `location`'s key value.

The order I'd like it to be is if the location is in the `MDF` then append those first, then if the location is in an `IDF` append those to the list after the `MDF` but in ascending order. So the final list would look like this:

```py
[
    {"hostname": "router-1.nunya.com", "location": "MDF"},
    {"hostname": "core-1.nunya.com", "location": "MDF"},
    {"hostname": "...", "location": "..."},
    {"hostname": "switch-1.nunya.com", "location": "IDF01"},
    {"hostname": "switch-2.nunya.com", "location": "IDF02"},
    {"hostname": "...", "location": "..."},
    {"hostname": "switch-30.nunya.com", "location": "IDF30"},
]
```

How can I modify my code to accomplish this?

Comment: `sorted(dev_dict.values(), key=itemgetter("location"))`?

Comment: @OlvinRoght that does sort it and put in order IDF first then MDF, so not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Add `reverse=True`

Comment: That'll sort it MDF first, but then the IDFs will be in Descending order. I want the list to be MDF first, then IDFs in ascending order.

Comment: You should open docs of `sorted()`, investigate how `key` argument works and adapt suggested code sample to your requirements. Or at least use search box on top to search for every particular problem. You need to pass lambda which will modify it's argument to achieve desired result, try to make it by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```py
# add a white space before MDF if location is MDF so that MDF locations come before all others
# (white space has the lowest ASCII value among printable characters)
sorted(dev_dict.values(), key=lambda d: " MDF" if (v:=d['location'])=='MDF' else v)

# another, much simpler way (from Olvin Roght)
sorted(dev_dict.values(), key=lambda d: d['location'].replace('MDF', ' MDF'))



# [{'hostname': 'router-a-1.nunya.com', 'location': 'MDF'},
#  {'hostname': 'core-1.nunya.com', 'location': 'MDF'},
#  {'hostname': '...', 'location': '...'},
#  {'hostname': 'switch-1.nunya.com', 'location': 'IDF01'},
#  {'hostname': 'switch-2.nunya.com', 'location': 'IDF02'},
#  {'hostname': 'switch-30.nunya.com', 'location': 'IDF30'}]
```

[Click here](https://www.ascii-code.com/) to see the complete ASCII table.